# "Managing of something" or "managing something"

Tags: differences

Which is the correct usage?

> *My responsibilities include managing of employee data.*

or

> *My responsibilities include managing
>   employee data.*

If both are correct, can they be used interchangeably or do they have different meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be **“…managing employee data”**, or alternatively **“…management of employee data”**.

Answer (score 1):

> My responsibilities include managing
>   employee data.

This is the correct statement. It's derived from "to manage something" -> "to manage employee data" -> "managing employee data".